# How to display all list values without endless loop

Tags: c++, list

I have a list and I want to display it's values.

I want to see `1 2 3 4`, but I have a endless loop like `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2..`

Can't understand, why?

```
struct node
{
    int item;
    node *next;

    node(int x, node *t)
    {
        item = x;
        next = t;
    }
};

int main()
{
    node *firstElement = new node(1, NULL);
    firstElement->next = firstElement;
    node *lastElement = firstElement;

    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
        lastElement = (lastElement->next = new node(i, firstElement));

    for (node *first = lastElement; first != 0; first = first->next)
        cout << first->item << " ";
    delete firstElement;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not use a debugger? `new node` very bad style since you don't even delete the nodes

Comment: @deW1 yes, thanks, forget about `delete`

Comment: You initialize the node with `next` set to `firstElement`; the last node never has its `next` pointer changed from this.

Comment: Thanks for answers, now it is all clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
struct node
{
  int item;
  node *next;

  node(int x, node *t)
  {
    item = x;
    next = t;
  }
};

int main()
{
  node *firstElement = new node(1, NULL);
  node *lastElement = firstElement;

  for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
    lastElement = (lastElement->next = new node(i, nullptr));

  for (node *first = firstElement; first != 0; first = first->next)
    cout << first->item << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

[IdeOne live code](http://ideone.com/dUxpeo)

The problem is that you set the "next" link of your last node to this node itself, not nullptr.
Also, it's better to delete the memory allocated

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your data structure has an infinite loop in itself: this line

```
firstElement->next = firstElement;
```

makes `firstElement` point back to itself, creating a circular list. When you add more elements, your list remains circular, so exit condition `first == 0` is never achieved.

If you want your list to remain linear, not circular, your insertion code should be modified as follows:

```
node *firstElement = new node(1, NULL);
node *lastElement = firstElement;

for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
    lastElement->next = new node(i, lastElement->next)
    lastElement = lastElement->next;
}
```

The printing code should start with `firstElement`:

```
for (node *current = firstElement; current != 0; current = current->next)
    cout << current->item << " ";
```

Finally, deleting a single `firstItem` is not sufficient. You need a loop to traverse the whole list. Alternatively, you could chain deletion in the destructor by calling `delete next`, but this is dangerous, because recursive invocation of destructors may overflow the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop in your list, because `lastElement->next` always points to `firstElement`. This is why `first` will never be equal to `0`.

If you really need a loop I think you should write something like this:

```
node* p = firstElement;
do {
    cout << p->item << " ";
    p = p->next;
} while (p != firstElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create every node with `firstElement` as its `next`.
This would make sense if you were adding nodes to the front of the list, but you're adding them at the back, so the last node will point back to the start.

Since you're adding to the back, terminate the list on every insertion instead:

```
lastElement->next = new node(i, nullptr))
```